# Meteor js 1.7 Click event not registering on mobile

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have built a simple homepage, where the navbar becomes a hamburger on small devices. On web (and mobile view in browser) this works fine. The navbar slides down, buttons work, etc.

When testing on actual mobile devices, the mobile nav is open by default when the page loads, and the hamburger does not respond to clicks/touches. I have not been able to figure out why it's open by default, but I am more concerned about the touch event firing right now.

I've read similar articles from 3+ years ago, and haven't found anything recent.

Navbar Template:

```
<template name="navbar">
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <img id="logo" src="/img/logo.png" alt="Logo.png">
        <nav class="site-nav {{menuStatus}}">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/" id="home"><i class="fa fa-home site-nav--icon"></i>Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about" id="about"><i class="fa fa-info site-nav--icon"></i>About</a></li>
                <li><a href="/services" id="services"><i class="fa fa-pencil site-nav--icon"></i>Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="/careers" id="careers"><i class="fa fa-usd site-nav--icon"></i>Careers</a></li>
                <li><a href="/contact" id="contact"><i class="fa fa-envelope site-nav--icon"></i>Contact</a></li>
                <button class="login" >Login</button>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="menu-toggle">
            <a href="#" class="hamburger"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Navbar associated js:

```
import './navbar.html';
import './navbar.css';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var'

Template.navbar.onCreated(function OnCreated() {
    this.menuStatus = new ReactiveVar(' ');
});

Template.navbar.helpers({
  menuStatus: function(){
      return Template.instance().menuStatus.get()
  }
});

Template.navbar.events({
    'click .menu-toggle': (e, template) => {
        let menuStatus = template.menuStatus.get();
        if (menuStatus == ' ') {
            template.menuStatus.set('site-nav--open');
        } else {
            template.menuStatus.set(' ');
        }
    },
});
```

I have tried using jquery to achieve the same thing, but with no luck. If anyone has any idea why this is happening, or guidance on a better practice to do this, I'd appreciate any input.

Comment: I'm not sure this will solve your problem (so I'll leave as a comment): you should use `const template = Template.instance();` inside your event handler instead of passing `template` as a parameter. Can you verify that the action is firing with some debug statements?

Comment: I don't think any event is firing when an item is clicked. I've tried to alert & log  when clicked, and nothing happens. This applies to jqueries `on('tap')` when I bind it to .menu-toggle as well.

Comment: My above comment is not entirely true. The event *does* fire, but it does not execute code to toggle the class. 

For example, if I add an event for touchstart, it will alert the message. It just will not toggle the class.
`'touchstart .menu-toggle': () => {
    alert('menu-toggle clicked');
});`

Comment: Did you try my suggestion above? What is `menuStatus` after you call `template.menuStatus.get();`?

Comment: It looks like you defined a method `click  .menu-toggle` but you've never called it.